# Overlay an image on google maps android api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I am trying to use GroundOverlay to add an image to my map. I'm working with the example from

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay

which is given like this

```
GoogleMap map = ...; // get a map.
BitmapDescriptor image = ...; // get an image.
LatLngBounds bounds = ...; // get a bounds
// Adds a ground overlay with 50% transparency.
GroundOverlay groundOverlay = map.addGroundOverlay(new GroundOverlayOptions()
 .image(image)
 .positionFromBounds(bounds)
 .transparency(0.5));
```

However I don't know how to get the image as a bitmapdescriptor. I also don't know how to input the latlngBounds. Any help would be appreciated, the only tutorials I can find online are for API v.1 and no longer seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[BitmapDescriptorFactory](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/BitmapDescriptorFactory) can create `BitmapDescriptor`s for you from various objects, e.g.

```
BitmapDescriptor image = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.myimage);
```

You don't need to use `positionFromBounds` if you don't want to. There are alternative ways to create from central `LatLng` and width in meters: [GroundOverlayOptions.position](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlayOptions#position%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng,%20float,%20float%29).

Comment: How would I do that specifically? for example, I have an image in R.drawable.myimage how would I use that in BitmapDescriptorFactory?

Comment: @user2653730 Just look into the documentation. Factory functions are listed there. Added example.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are an absolute life saver! It's embarrassing how long I've been struggling with that.

Comment: @user2653730 Glad I could help. I consider myself relative life saver. Absolute things are deprecated in Android since 1.5.