# Memory efficient google map drawing on Android

Tags: android, performance, google-maps, memory, overlay

I'm trying to draw several spots on a GoogleMap using APIv2 on Android with support libraries.
I have several arrays of SPOT objects, containing latitude and longitude of said spots.
Each time I want to draw the spots on the map, I call the following method:

```
public void drawSpotsFromArray(ArrayList<Spot> pSpots, int pZIndex) {

    for (int i=0; i<pSpots.size(); i++) {
        Spot lSpot = pSpots.get(i);

        double lDiameter = 10;

        CircleOptions lCircleOptions = new CircleOptions();
        lCircleOptions.center(new LatLng(lSpot.mLatitude, lSpot.mLongitude));
        lCircleOptions.radius(lDiameter);
        lCircleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
        lCircleOptions.strokeWidth(5);
        lCircleOptions.fillColor(Color.WHITE);
        lCircleOptions.zIndex(pZIndex);

        mGoogleMap.addCircle(lCircleOptions);
    }
}
```

It just draws every spot contained in the array.
Now, my problem is that these arrays are quite big, resulting in a memory overload. I draw about 500 circles (5 arrays of 100 circles), so the app gets very slow.

Is there a way, instead of drawing each circle as a single overlay, draw each table of spots as a single overlay? For example, drawing 100 circles of an array as one overlay, resulting in 5 overlays (5 arrays) instead of 500 overlays (the arrays' circles).

If so, would it be more memory-efficient?
If not, what would be the best practice to draw these circles without consuming all the device's memory?

Each time I call this method, I give a higher zIndex. I don't know if this is impacting the memory in any way.
Thank you for your help.

**EDIT:**

OK, the algorithm in the answers below helped me to solve my problem, along with this thread to draw a ground overlay with a drawable:
[Ground Overlay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18062363/overlay-an-image-on-google-maps-android-api-v2)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try a slightly different approach.  Only draw the Spots on the map if that part of the map is visible.  You'll need to call it again each time your camera position moves.

Try something like this:

```
    public void drawSpotsFromArray(ArrayList<Spot> pSpots, int pZIndex) {

    LatLngBounds bounds = mGoogleMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;

    for (int i = 0; i < pSpots.size(); i++) {
        Spot lSpot = pSpots.get(i);

        if (bounds.contains(new LatLng(lSpot.Latitude, lSpot.Longitude))) {
            double lDiameter = 10;

            CircleOptions lCircleOptions = new CircleOptions();
            lCircleOptions.center(new LatLng(lSpot.mLatitude,
                    lSpot.mLongitude));
            lCircleOptions.radius(lDiameter);
            lCircleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);
            lCircleOptions.strokeWidth(5);
            lCircleOptions.fillColor(Color.WHITE);
            lCircleOptions.zIndex(pZIndex);

            mGoogleMap.addCircle(lCircleOptions);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to be good. I just see two problems: first, if I draw a circle, move it out of the screen and come back, how should I know that it has already been drawn? (I can't keep a boolean for every spot). Second, if the map shows all visible spots at once, I mean, all of the 500, the problem will be the same. This can occur in some configurations. What would you suggest then? I'm gonna do this approach to improve responsiveness for now if the map is zoomed in.

Comment: I'd clear the map of all spots before redrawing them.          mGoogleMap.clear()

Comment: Ok, I think I can do that. Just for the last point, what would you do if I am to display all of them at once? This happens when the user wants to display everything and opens the app, the camera is zoomed out a shows every spot.

Comment: Using a drawable rather than creating a circle for each post would be faster.  I'm assuming that you have a reason for creating a that many circles manually.  A drawable would cause far fewer problems.  If you're set on doing it this way, then maybe have a look at clustering so you don't show as many circles when teh map is zoomed out.

Comment: Well, the reason I use circles is that I read the Google documentation about how I should draw a circle. I'll use a drawable if it's more memory efficient. Will a drawable be scaled or fixed in the same way when zooming? I mean, I thought drawables were to be used as markers, and couldn't be used as overlays. How would you replace the circle options code with a drawable (and by the way, what size should the drawable be to match the 10 meters diameter on any screen?).

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are seeing the delay is because you are trying to plot 500 element on a map on the UI thread which will certainly slow things down.

The proper way to do what you want IMO would be to get the map projection and only plot the circles that are viewable at the current time and keeping a boolean or something to indicate that the circle was plotted. Doing this will decrease the slowness of the app since it is not plotting everything and would eventually result in all items being plotted on the map (assuming all circles were viewable) so you eventually wouldn't have to plot anything anymore.